# Change HTML text and saveback to HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am working on a simple way to wrap each sentence of an ebook formatted in HTML in span tags.

I am using a trained machine learning model to classify end of sentence punctuation (".!?" ...) and get the real sentences boundaries (ex: in U.S.A, "S" is not considered a sentence).

The problem is, in order to feed my model correct data, I need to first extract the text out of my HTML ebook (using BeautifulSoup's `get_text('\n')`).

Right now, I am able to wrap the output of `get_text('\n')` in span tags. But I can't just save that since I loose all the other tags used in the original HTML ebook.

Example HTML ebook sample:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><title> Name. Of the book. </title></head> ...
</div>
```

After `get_text`

```
Name. Of the book.
```

After running my algorithm:

```
<span>Name. Of the book.</span>
```

How can I get this output instead:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><title> <span>Name. Of the book.</span> </title></head> ...
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: create full HTML with all needed information and then save it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wrap()` method ([doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#wrap)) to wrap the text into `<span>` tags - it will update the whole HTML structure.

Example:

```
data = '''<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><title> Name. Of the book. </title></head>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print('Before:')
print('-' * 80)
print(soup.prettify())
print('-' * 80)

for text in soup.find_all(text=True):
    text.wrap(soup.new_tag("span"))     # use wrap() function to wrap the text into <span> tag

print('After:')
print('-' * 80)
print(soup.prettify())
print('-' * 80)
```

Prints (notice the `<span>` inside the `<title>` tag):

```
Before:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <title>
   Name. Of the book.
  </title>
 </head>
</html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
After:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <title>
   <span>
    Name. Of the book.
   </span>
  </title>
 </head>
</html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have a pretty naive but quite effective approach. You can get the entire html code first and then store it in a string and then use `Regular Expression` on it to extract the texts of the `span` tag.
This is the only way I can think of as of now. Hope this helps :)